# Unable to access variable from base .php called by required php

Tags: php

assume i have a code as below:

**index.php**

```
<?php
    require 'file_1.php';

    // file_1.php contents can go here, but i'm trying to make this simple and clutter free, thus clean. 
    // The reason being to not centralize all code in a single file should file_2.php, file_3.php, file_n.php exist.

    $app = new type_of_object();
    $app->intialize_some_stuff();
?>
```

**file_1.php**

```
<?php
    $app->access_some_method($param1, new function($app) {
        // do some logic here...
    });
?>
```

doing this approach, i get an error such as below:

> Notice: Undefined variable: app in X:\project_folder\file_1.php on line 2

to summarize, i'm trying to decentralize all codes from being defined in `index.php` and instead, have them hosted by different files such as `file_1.php` to `file_n.php`. The problem is, i'd be needing to access the `$app` variable from `index.php` on the *required* files such as `file_1.php` to `file_n.php` since i'll only need 1 instance of this, no duplicates allowed.

i'm also open to being taught another approach on this.

cheers!

EDIT: its worth nothing that i'm fairly new in PHP, and that i've already done few research. except that what i'm getting is the opposite of my issue. also, the need to access `$app` of `index.php` from other php files is the very center of my question.

Comment: @RodenerDajes can you provide me more details on this? also, can i pass `$app` of `index.php` to other php files with this?

Comment: You need to instantiate the object before you can use it. You are doing the opposite—first you include `file_1.php` which contains code that assumes that an `$app` object has been created. However, you don't actually create the object until after the `include`.

Comment: By way of advice, you could `include` the file after instantiation, but there's no benefit to this really. I'd consider moving the instantiation to the included file if it's part of some shared functionality.

Comment: @DarraghEnright i moved the `require 'file_1.php` after `$app = new type_of_object()` and it majestically worked. i didn't know one can place that systax anywhere in the code, i thought it should just stay at the top most part.

Comment: @DarraghEnright yes that solved my problem. can you also explain to me why there's no benefit to this? i'd like to know more about this so i can use it as a reference for future projects :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting code can be a good idea to achieve a better maintainability. You should avoid unclear scripts name.

at a high degree, you want definitely go on [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) approach  to maintain packages.

Anyway, for a basic code splitting, the rules are the same than a regular script. Code is interpreted at the time it is read. Just rewrite your example in one script :

```
<?php
    $app->access_some_method($param1, new function($app) {
        // do some logic here...
    });

    $app = new type_of_object();
    $app->intialize_some_stuff();
?>
```

See the problem ? `$app` is simply not initialized when calling the `access_some_method`.

So, this will work :

```
<?php
    $app = new type_of_object();
    $app->intialize_some_stuff();
    require 'file_1.php';
?>
```

But the gain is poor. If you already have a class, there's a few cases where it can be interesting to split logic among many files. I think this one is a better example (all files in the same folder, no namespaces) :

```
<?php
   require('App');
   require('AppRequest');

   $app = new App();
   $request = new AppRequest();
   $app->process($request);
```

With this way, you can split the main app logic and the request analysis logic for instance

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. i really wasn't that used to the fact that PHP is an interpreted language since i actually use C# for most of the time. your answer definitely answered my problem. however, for the latter recommendation. i still do not understand how `$app->process($request);` would work nor it's hypothetical content that would reference an instance of `$app` inside the function. i'm fairly new to PHP and i'd like to learn a lot of things including this one first. but then again, thank you! :)

Comment: only if possible, could you also possibly share the content of the `App()` and `AppRequest()` classes including the `->process($request);` method. it can be in pastebin or any other online paste tool. i'd like to use this as a basis, also a reference for other new PHP Developers.

Comment: You're welcome. The example was a fake only to demonstrate some kind of logic. You can have a look at https://phptherightway.com to dig further when beginning PHP. The main idea is to create processes "specialists" through classes that will be instantiated by the main script as needed.